# probability of runners finishing in specific order

Tags: probability

Suppose 26 athletes (Alice, Bob, Charlie, Derek.....Zak) run a race and each ordering of the athletes is equally likely. What's the probability that Alice finishes before Bob, and Bob finishes before Charlie.

For this I thought the answer was 1/4 because I thought that there are half of the possibilites where Alice is before Bob and half where Bob finishes before Charlie. So I did `1/2 *1/2` but I realize that has some overlaps and the number isn't correct. How do I go about finding the answer for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Ignore the other 23 runners. If there were only those 3 runners in the race, what would your answer be?

**Hint:** What are the possible outcomes of such a race? In which outcome would Alice be before Bob, and Bob be before Charlie?

Comment: there would be a 1/6 chance of this outcome. So for this there would be one outcome as well... but the number of possibilites is 2^26?

Comment: @userunknown Perfect. Now, why do the other 23 runners not matter?

Comment: because the order where they would place is irrelevant. it is all reletive to Alie, Bob and Charlie.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Forget about the other runners. All relative orders of our three heroes are, by assumption, equally likely.